# Changing the default calendar reminder time in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, notifications, reminder

I've got a simple question but I have yet to find a simple answer. Hoping someone on here can help me out.

The question is: How do I change the default reminder time in Outlook 2010 for a specific calendar?

Note: I know that going to File > Options > Calendar > Calendar options and playing with "Default reminders" will apply for all calendars (or at least I assume this is the case). But shouldn't I be able to edit (or remove) the default reminders on a calendar-by-calendar basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be nice, but sorry, you simply cannot.

In fact, it was a well-know bug out there that if you tried to set the default greater than 18 hours, it would just changes it back to 18 hours. They finally fixed that in SP1, released recently.

Comment: I mentioned that bug so if you don't have SP1, you won't struggle with that as a separate problem as I did on my system at one time.